# How to use opengl with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, opengl

Flutter 1.12 was released with support ffi, we could bind native C/C++ lib and use for flutter, I searched and  found out some opengl bind for dart, I dont know much about flutter, My questions are:
Could we able bind opengl to use with flutter for android and ios, and if we could, how to create widget with opengl canvas like glsurfaceview of android.

Comment: Looking to do something similar, did you come anywhere with this?

Comment: There is plenty of libraries: https://pub.dev/packages?q=flutter+opengl

Answer (score 2):

Add this Package

```
dependencies:
  flgl: ^0.0.6
```

---

```
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/geometries/flutter3d_box.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/geometries/flutter3d_cone.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/geometries/flutter3d_cylinder.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/geometries/flutter3d_triangle.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/textures/flutter3d_assets_texture.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/edge_geometry/flutter3d_box_edges_example.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/flutter3d_examples.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/geometries/flutter3d_multiple_geometries.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/geometries/flutter3d_plane.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/textures/flutter3d_plane_with_texture.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/examples/geometries/flutter3d_sphere.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flgl_example/home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Named Routes Demo',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const Home(),

        // flutter3D examples
        '/flutter3d_examples': (context) => const Flutter3DExamples(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/triangle': (context) => const Flutter3DTriangle(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/plane': (context) => const Flutter3DPlane(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/box': (context) => const Flutter3DBox(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/sphere': (context) => const Flutter3DSphere(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/cone': (context) => const Flutter3DCone(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/cylinder': (context) => const Flutter3DCylinder(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/multiple_geometries': (context) => const Flutter3DMultipleGeometries(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/plane_geometry_with_texture': (context) => const Flutter3DPlaneWithTexture(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/plane_assets_texture': (context) => const Flutter3DAssetsTexture(),
        '/flutter3d_examples/box_edges_example': (context) => const Flutter3DBoxEdgesExample(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```